# simplify query for all events by latest 20 "created-events"

Tags: postgresql

Given this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE notification_event (
    id                  bigserial   PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id             bigint      NOT NULL,
    notification_id     bigint      NOT NULL,
    server_timestamp    timestamptz NOT NULL,
    type                varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    data                jsonb       NOT NULL
);
```

and it is known that there is only a single `type='created'` event per `notification_id`.

I want to select *all* events associated with the `notification_id` of the latest 20 `type='created'` events for `user_id=8`.

I came up with this query, which does what I want, but it feels cumbersome to have 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM notification_event
WHERE notification_id IN (
  SELECT notification_id
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT notification_id, server_timestamp
      FROM notification_event
      WHERE user_id = 8
        AND type = 'created'
      ORDER BY server_timestamp DESC
  ) x
  ORDER BY server_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY server_timestamp DESC
```

How can I simplify this query?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah one level of subquery seems entirely redundant.  If each notification_id can only have one `type = 'created'` record, then the distinct seems pointless and so does the subquery it is in.

```
SELECT * FROM notification_event
WHERE notification_id IN (
  SELECT notification_id
  FROM notification_event
  WHERE user_id = 8 AND type = 'created'
  ORDER BY server_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 20 
)             
ORDER BY server_timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: makes sense. But to better understand: If there could be multiple `type = 'created'` events then the `DISTINCT` would be required and then the additional subquery would be required? (because we cannot sort on timestamp when using DISTINCT without also selecting the timestamp)

Comment: In that case, the think the question is ill defined.  If the same notification_id shows up more than once in the top 20 (but with different time stamps), what is supposed happen?  Do you want to see those records twice?  Or ignore the dup and pull the next notification_id to make up for it?  In the latter case I don't think SQL offers an efficient way to do it, you would need DISTINCT ON rather than just DISTINCT, and it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.